# Where are run the Opengl commands?

Tags: opengl, gpu

i'm programming a simple OpenGL program on a multi-core computer that has a GPU. The GPU is a simple GeForce with PhysX, CUDA and OpenGL 2.1 support. When i run this program, is the host CPU that executes OpenGL specific commands or the ones are directly transferred
to the GPU ???

Comment: You should be more specific. What is your program doing? What parts of OpenGL do you use? Any specific vendor extensions? Shaders?

Comment: It's a simple program. Only a 3D cube without extensions and shaders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally that's a function of the drivers you're using.  If you're just using vanilla VGA drivers, then all of the OpenGL computations are done on your CPU.  Normally, however, and with modern graphics cards and production drivers, calls to OpenGL routines that your graphics card's GPU can handle in hardware are performed there.  Others that the GPU can't perform are handed off to the CPU.